# Prevent ability to add "instance variables" dynamically Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I was wondering if there is a way to disallow the following in javascript:

```
var c = new Circle(4);
c.garbage = "Oh nooo!"; // Prevent this!!
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT: I was just about to give up on this, but I decided to check to see what the gods do (jQuery dev team).. how do they accomplish this?**

```
$('#Jimbo').hello = "hi!";
alert($('#Jimbo').hello); // undefined
```

**EDIT 2: Stupid mistake.. If you do this:**

```
var hi = $('#Jimbo');
hi.hello = "hi!";
alert(hi.hello); // You get "hi!"
```

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Comment: The reason that you get 'undefined there is because the object that is created when you call $('#Jimbo') on the first line is destroyed by the time you get to the second line.  Try assigning $('#Jimbo') to a variable and referencing the variable on the second line, then see what happens.

Comment: Ahhh good call.. stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't. Javascript allows members to be dynamically added and there isn't a hook to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (and I could be wrong)... There is no way to prevent this. That the point of having a 'dynamic' language... if someone makes a typo or adds on a random field then thats life...

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 5 defines `Object.preventExtensions` which can prevent new properties from being added to your precious object:

```
var c = new Circle(4);
Object.preventExtensions(c); // prevents new property additions on c
c.garbage = "Oh nooo!"; // fail
```

The spec also defines `Object.seal`, and `Object.freeze` which prevent property deletion and property mutation (respectively). More info [here](http://blog.thejit.org/2009/11/08/ecma-harmony-and-the-future-of-javascript/) and in [ECMA-262, 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (pdf).

Of course, this is of no current significance to you at all, but is exactly what you're after :)

Comment: Ohh interesting! I'm not up with the whole EMCAScript stuff, but is that the new specs for the javascript interpreter?

Comment: @Matt: yes, JavaScript engines will be integrating features of ECMAScript 5 in time. There is no public ECMAScript 5 implementation that I know of.

Comment: Just chiming int to let everyone know that this works in Chrome currently. Version 25.0.1364.152 m

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: nice. [Here are more browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).